# Pyenv's python is missing bzip2 module

Tags: python, pyenv, bzip2

I used pyenv to install python 3.8.2 and to create a virtualenv.
In the virtualenv, I used pipenv to install `pandas`.

However, when importing pandas, I'm getting the following:

```
  [...]
  File "/home/luislhl/.pyenv/versions/poc-prefect/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/common.py", line 3, in <module>
    import bz2
  File "/home/luislhl/.pyenv/versions/3.8.2/lib/python3.8/bz2.py", line 19, in <module>
    from _bz2 import BZ2Compressor, BZ2Decompressor
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_bz2'
```

After some googling, I found out some people suggesting I rebuild Python from source after installing bzip2 library in my system.

However, after trying installing it with `sudo dnf install bzip2-devel` I see that I already had it installed.

As far as I know, pyenv builds python from source when installing some version.
So, why wasn't it capable of including the bzip2 module when building?

How can I manage to rebuild Python using pyenv in order to make bzip2 available?
I'm in Fedora 30

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE**
I tried installing another version of python with pyenv in verbose mode, to see the compilation output.

There is this message in the end of the compilation:

```
WARNING: The Python bz2 extension was not compiled. Missing the bzip2 lib?
```

But as I stated before, I checked I already have bzip2 installed in my system. So I don't know what to do.

Comment: Add some information about your operating system and also try `pip install bzip2` in the virtual env and add the output of that.

Comment: `bzip2` doesn't seem to be a valid package: https://pypi.org/project/bzip2/

Comment: Sorry, I guess it is `bz2`

Comment: `bz2` doesn't work either: `Could not find a version that matches bz2`

Answer (score 81, accepted):

On Ubuntu 22 LTS

#### Missing Library Problem in Python Installation with Pyenv

Before the fix:

```
$> pyenv install 3.11.0
```

command result:

```
pyenv: /home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.11.0 already exists
continue with installation? (y/N) y
Downloading Python-3.11.0.tar.xz...
-> https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.11.0/Python-3.11.0.tar.xz


Installing Python-3.11.0...
WARNING: The Python bz2 extension was not compiled. Missing the bzip2 lib?
WARNING: The Python readline extension was not compiled. Missing the GNU readline lib?
WARNING: The Python lzma extension was not compiled. Missing the lzma lib?
```

#### TLDR;

Recipe to fix:

```bash
sudo apt-get install build-essential zlib1g-dev libffi-dev libssl-dev libbz2-dev libreadline-dev libsqlite3-dev liblzma-dev
```

#### Result

After the fix:

```bash
$> pyenv install 3.11.0
```

Command result:

```
pyenv: /home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.11.0 already exists
continue with installation? (y/N) y
Downloading Python-3.11.0.tar.xz...
-> https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.11.0/Python-3.11.0.tar.xz
Installing Python-3.11.0...
Installed Python-3.11.0 to /home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.11.0
```

Comment: This command line alone would not be enough (at least for me). You should also install tkinter with this:
`sudo apt-get install python-tk python3-tk tk-dev`


And add the ncurses library to your previous cmd:
`sudo apt-get install build-essential zlib1g-dev libffi-dev libssl-dev libbz2-dev libreadline-dev libsqlite3-dev liblzma-dev libncurses-dev`

Comment: I had the same problem with pyenv doctor and the fix solved the issue

Comment: See [suggested-build-environment](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/wiki#suggested-build-environment) in pyenv documentation.

Comment: I had the same issue trying installing python 3.8 using pyenv also I have to included tkinter packages as @AlexNeaKameni mentioned. Ubuntu 22 lts

Answer (score 15):

On macOS Big Sur, to get pyenv ( via homebrew ) to work I had to install zlib and bzip2 via homebrew and then add the exports in my ~/.zshrc ( or ~/.bashrc for bash I guess).  The answer above [by luislhl](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60775172/2117661) leads the way to my solution.

```
brew install zlib bzip2

#Add the following to your ~/.zshrc
# For pyenv to build
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/zlib/lib -L/usr/local/opt/bzip2/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/zlib/include -I/usr/local/opt/bzip2/include"

# Then the install worked
pyenv install 3.7.9
```

Comment: There is a typo in the CPPFLAGS. The include folder should be `bzip2`, not `bzip3`

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I have found the solution after some time. It was simple, but I took some time to realize it.

It turns out the problem was the `bzip2-devel` I had installed was a 32-bit version.

The compilation process was looking for the 64-bit one, and didn't find it.
So I had to specifically install the 64-bit version:

```
sudo dnf install bzip2-devel-1.0.6-29.fc30.x86_64
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, that helped, just with small modification in `~/.zshrc`:

```
export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/zlib/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/bzip2/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/zlib/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/bzip2/include"
```

and then `pyenv install 3.7.9`

---

`Apple M1`, `macOS 11.1 20C69 arm64`;

```
➜ brew --version           
Homebrew 2.7.1
Homebrew/homebrew-core (git revision ad6fd8; last commit 2021-01-05)
Homebrew/homebrew-cask (git revision 5c3de; last commit 2021-01-04)
```

---

but this didn't help with `No module named '_ctypes'` on M1 :(

Comment: I think that for the sake of completeness it is probably better always let HomeBrew find out its own path and use these declarations `export LDFLAGS="-L$(brew --prefix zlib)/lib -L$(brew --prefix bzip2)/lib"` and `export CPPFLAGS="-I$(brew --prefix zlib)/include -I$(brew --prefix bzip2)/include"`

Answer (score 0):

For me, on Fedora 39, to get pyenv to work I had to install the following packages

```
sudo dnf install bzip2-devel ncurses-devel libffi-devel readline-devel tk-devel libsqlite3x-devel
```